# Perl return array from multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, reference, grep

I've got this multidimensional array:

```
@valid_values = (["val00", "val01", "val02"], ["val10", "val11", "val12"]);
```

Via grep I want to check, if a certain value exists within the first array of the multidimensional array.
I've tried something like this:

```
if (grep $_ eq $check_value, @valid_values[0]) {print "ok\n"}
```

This doesn't work though. I've also tried using `$valid_values[0]`, but I think this will only return a reference to the array, so I used `@` to dereference it.

Any suggestions on how I can return the whole first array of the 2d-array, so I can use it for the grep function?

Comment: Dereference first element as array `grep .., @{ $valid_values[0] }`

Comment: Perl has extensive documentation [perldsc](https://metacpan.org/pod/perldsc). Also, never use `@a[0]`, always `$a[0]`.

Comment: @C you should add that as an answer so people can find it easier in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element of `@valid_values` is accessed as `$valid_values[0]`.

The value in the first element is an array reference. To dereference an array reference, you use `@{ ... }`.

So to get the array referenced by the array reference in the first element of `@valid_values` you want `@{ $valid_values[0] }`.

For more details about how to deal with data structures like this, see [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html), [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).